# Конвертирование целочисленное представление даты в pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Как преобразовать столбец с датами в целочисленном виде в привычный формат представления даты и времени?

```
0     1639676580
1     1639676640
2     1639676700
3     1639676760
4     1639676820
5     1639676880
6     1639676940
7     1639677000
8     1639677060
9     1639677120

Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Хочу получить такой столбец в итоге

```
0 2021-12-16 20:44:00
1 2021-12-16 20:45:00
2 2021-12-16 20:46:00
3 2021-12-16 20:47:00
4 2021-12-16 20:48:00
5 2021-12-16 20:49:00
6 2021-12-16 20:50:00
7 2021-12-16 20:51:00
8 2021-12-16 20:52:00
9 2021-12-16 20:53:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом конвертации pandas:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')
```

Обратите внимание на параметр `unit` - если вы не укажите его, у вас расчет будет в наносекундах с начала эпохи Unix, и вы получите неверные даты.